# Exported Database is Empty

Tags: php, database, mysql

I have a code to backup my database by using `mysqldump`. However, the output is a file with blank data inside. Below is the script.

```
$command = "mysqldump -u root -p vti_ctes_demo > db/backupfile.sql";
system($command);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql

it looks like you forgetting to type the password

Comment: hi, there is no pswd for it. i tried again, but still doesn't work.

Comment: if there is no pass then try to drop '-p' parameter

Comment: Make sure write permissions are set on the folder you are dumping to.

Comment: i got it now. I need to place the 'mysqldump' application into the folder. thanks alot all for the help. really appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between -p and the password.

`$command = "mysqldump -u root -pvti_ctes_demo > db/backupfile.sql";`

Comment: He states that there is no password.